# Create a subclass from its superclass - Swift

Tags: swift, class, inheritance, arkit, realitykit

I have a custom class inheriting from `Entity`:

```
class VirtualObject: Entity {
    var raycast: ARTrackedRaycast?

    func stopTrackedRaycast() {
        raycast?.stopTracking()
        raycast = nil
    }
}
```

So, what I wanted to is to create a new `VirtualObject` that has everything from the `Entity` that I receive from a completion handler

Here's the completion handler:

```
cancellable = Entity
    .loadAsync(named: "toy_drummer")
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { (error) in
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }) { (entity /* <- THIS is the entity */) in
    // Here we need to create a new VirtualObject from entity
}
```